# MTKView not visible a certain resolutions

Tags: ios, resolution, metal

Shaders (fragment) are not drawing on screen at some resolutions.

**Working:** 720x1280, 888x1024, 128x128, 1920x1080, 1080x1920, 1125x2436, 500x500

**Not working:** 1280x720, 1024x888, 256x256, 512x512, 1024x1024, 1536x1536, 768x768

In all examples tho, the pixel data of my `MTKView`'s `CAMetalDrawable`'s `MTLTexture`, looks good. To debug, I printed out a grid of ascii art of sampled pixels and I see the expected image. Also tested converting the texture to an image and added it to an image view, and see the result.

Also now tested with converting the MTLTexture to a UIImage and all resolutions look good.

So the render is always successful, tho it's like a 50/50 chance it renders on screen.

Anyone seen this before?

[Here's the render setup.](https://github.com/hexagons/pixels/blob/feature/live/Source/PixelsRender.swift#L168)

Tested on iOS 12, Xcode 10 & 10.2, on iPhone X & iPad Pro.

Comment: Fragment or Compute shaders?

Comment: You're going to need to show code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Fragment shaders.

Comment: @KenThomases It's a big framework so it's hard to isolate where it could be, tho updated the post with a link to the render setup code.